# Combining TCP Server and DASH as threads gives "No attribute Dash"

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp

I am trying to synchronize two threads in a python script to work. The idea is the first thread to be a TCP Server, that would receive data from the client, save the data in a variable and the same variable should be given to the second thread a DASH script that would create a graph. By using the threads I want to make it possible the graph to update itself when new data is received in the TCP server e.g. list gets updated.

Code:

```
app = dash.Dash()

def dash():
    app.layout = html.Div([
     html.H1('Hardware Praktikum'),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='my-dropdown',
         options=[
            {'label': 'Tesla', 'value': 'TSLA'},
            {'label': 'Apple', 'value': 'AAPL'}
        ],
          value='TSLA'
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id='my-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])

    @app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'), [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])

    def update_graph(selected_dropdown_value):

        return {
            'data': list }

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server()

def server():
    HOST = '******' # Server IP or Hostname
    PORT = 22000 
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print 'Socket created'

#managing error exception

    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
#except socket.error:
#   print socket.error
    #print 'Bind failed '

    s.listen(5)
    print 'Socket awaiting messages'
    (conn, addr) = s.accept()
    print 'Connected'

#List to save data
    list = []
# awaiting for message
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print 'Received data: ' + data
        reply = ''

        # process your message
        #break if no data
        if not data:
            break
        elif ("close"):
            break
        else:
            #append new data
            data=data.split(",")
            list.append((float(data[0]),float(data[1])))    
            reply = 'Saved'

        # Sending reply
        conn.send(reply)

    conn.close() # Close connections




dash = threading.Thread(target=dash)
server = threading.Thread(target=server)

server.start()
dash.start()
```

From my point of view the logic behind it should do the job. Apparently I am wrong.. I get a

> AtributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'Dash'

Comment: Your indentation is completely off, could you please correct it?

Comment: I am sorry @Torxed but I dont understand what am I supposed to correct :( Indentation ?

Comment: You just did. The indentation of `def update_graph` for instance. Is this actually what your code looks like? is `if __name__ == '__main__':` supposed to be inside `def update_graph()`? :)

Comment: Okay, now I understand, no it was a mistake... I have corrected it

Comment: Is `update_graph` meant to be in `dash()`? If not, please correct **all** the indentation, not just the stuff I point out to you :)

Comment: I have already double checked them, the rest of them are as planned. To explain, at the beginning I had two separate scripts one for the TCP Server and another for the DASH. Then I thought it would be interesting to combine them in one and do the whole process with threads.  Key element would be the LIST which is updated in server() and used in dash()